# Icon Font wont work in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have to create a stroke effect on icons that are a font. I have tried the text-shadow technique but the problem is it comes out very choppy, so what I ended up doing is separating the outline from the icon and exporting that as a font an then again merging them on to each other.

It works perfect now!... Just not in IE.

I am not quiet sure how much better i can explain my problem other then showing you all:
custom fonts does not work in jsfiddle so I have temporarily upoaded it to - http://babysignlanguage.co.za/icon_fonts/

Heres the code:

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {background:#99FFCC;}
.menu_icon_gen {font-size: 6em; font-family: 'icomoon';}
.space { letter-spacing:-2em; zoom:1;}
.left {float:left;}
.green {color:#ACBB72;}
.white {color:#FFF;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu_icon_gen" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="green space left">&#xe000;</span> 
    <span class="white">&#xe001;</span>
```

```
<div class="menu_icon_gen" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="green space left">&#xe002;</span> 
    <span class="white">&#xe003;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It kinda works if you set letter-spacing to `-1em` (which would make more sense, any reason why it's -2?)

Comment: Very true, but even so at -1em in IE it the phone icon still wont work and the house i con is out of place and still no go in ie7

Comment: Ah right, I see now. I recently had font issues as well in IE, in the end I just gave up :(

Comment: ah i see thanks, I'm stupid enough to refuse to give up though :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave `position: relative` to the `div`, and `position: absolute` to the `span`.

Works for me in IE 9.

[image]

Comment: That's odd it works for me now in IE7 but not IE9 and IE8... :\, Typical IE

Comment: Hey, your solution worked as soon as i removed letter-spacing. thanks :)